# Tangent half angle formula in terms of area and semiperimeter of a triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I found this formula while solving some JEE advanced questions:

$$ \tan \frac{X}{2} = \frac{\Delta}{S(S-x)}$$

I suppose $\Delta $ is area of the the triangle and $S$ is the semiperimeter with $X$ being the angle and $x$ being the side opposite to it.

What is the name of the above formula? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: I don't know if this has a name, *per se*. It's a fairly simple observation that readily follows from (1) $\Delta=rs$ (where $r$ is the inradius), and (2) $S-x$ is the length of the tangent segment from $X$ to the incircle.

Comment: Nice, thanks @Blue

Comment: See S, L. Loney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heron's formula for calculating the area of triangle in therms of measures of it's sides:

$S=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$

where S is area of triangle, $p=\frac12(a+b+c)$ where a, b, c are measure of the sides of triangle.

$\tan (\frac{\alpha}2)=\sqrt{\frac{(p-b)(p-c)}{p(p-a)}}$

multiplying numerator and denominator of fraction under the radical by $p(p-a)$ we obtain:

$$\tan (\frac{\alpha}2)=\sqrt{\frac{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}{(p(p-a))^2}}=\frac S{p(p-a)}$$

$\alpha$ is angle opposite to side a.

Comment: And where does the formula you mentioned for the tangent of the half angle formula come from? How is it derived?

Comment: @jsmith, this is well known formula. you can find the way it is derived in Wiki.You can also ask , surely you get a good answer.